# XAMARIN open specific Browser

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am currently working on a XAMARIN app that should open a web page in a specific browser.

The goal is not to open the default browser and also not in the app. Clicking a button should open for example the DuckDuckGo browser or Chrome, even if it is not the default.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=ios) only show how to open a browser, but I want to open a specific browser if it is installed.

Example:

```
    public async void OpenSpecificBrowser(string url)
    {
        //I don't wont default or in-app
        //Open link in firefox even if not default
        await Browser.OpenAsync(@"firefox://https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qF8f_0DYwog/maxresdefault.jpg");
    }
```

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: do those apps have custom url schemes registered?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how the browsers are built up on mobile phones... On Windows I know that I can enter the URL as a start parameter for the program. However, this does not work with Xamarin. But if someone knows more about this I am glad about any information!

Comment: custom url schemes are an Android/iOS concept, not anything specific to Xamarin.  A cursory search makes it look like they aren't used by the major mobile browsers, so there might not be a way to solve this.